# How to set the real ip in a request going from nginx to a backend server

Tags: nginx

I have my backend servers fronted with nginx. When a user sends a request to my backend, it hits the NginX and then it is routed to the backend server. There, I publish some stats and one of them is the client IP. In my setup, its the Nginx IP which gets published as the client IP. Is there a way and a config to set the real IP of the client?

Following is my config.

```
server {
        listen   8280;
        server_name my.server.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout 5m;
                proxy_send_timeout 5m;
                proxy_pass http://myserver_http/;
        }

        access_log /mnt/var/log/nginx/myserver/access.log;
        error_log /mnt/var/log/nginx/myserver/error.log;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to forward the real client IP use inside your location block:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
```